# How can I annotate the number as type in parametric type

Tags: generics, types, julia

Im newbie to julia.

I was curious about value type in julia so I test them few.

```
using StaticArrays
struct MT{N,Np1}
    x::SVector{N,Int}
    y::SVector{Np1,Int}
    function MT(x::SVector{T,Int},y::SVector{V,Int}) where {T, V}
        Val{T}() == Val{V}() || throw(ArgumentError("mismatched lengths; y must be one element longer than x"))
        new{T, V}(x,y)
    end
end

MT(SVector{3,Int}(1,2,3),SVector{3,Int}(1,2,3))
```

My question is this:

1. Can I annotate type of T and V in where clause?
   (Like "where {T=Int, V=Int}" or something?)
2. Can we restrict the type of T as Integer by using type annotation?
   (Allow MT{1,1} but not MT{1.0, 1.0})

I want working code with type annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question about restricting the type of parameters `T` and `V` is that you cannot do that for non-type/value parameters. It would be nice, but you can't.

Only subtype relationships can be enforced on type paramaters, and value-parameters cannot be in a subtype relationship:

```
julia> 3 isa Integer  # this is a valid relationship
true

julia> 3 <: Integer  # this is not
ERROR: TypeError: in <:, expected Type, got a value of type Int64
```

A hypothetical syntax could instead be `where {T::Int, V::Int}`, or `where {T isa Int, V isa Int}`. I don't know why this is not possible, but it is a well-known limitation.

BTW: You can just write `T == V`. No need for `Val{T}() == Val{V}()`. The computation happens at compile time, since both are type parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct MT{N,Np1}
    x::SVector{N,Int}
    y::SVector{Np1,Int}
    function MT(x::SVector{T,Int},y::SVector{V,Int}) where T <: Integer where V <: Int
        Val{T}() == Val{V}() || throw(ArgumentError("mismatched lengths; y must be one element longer than x"))
        new{T, V}(x,y)
    end
end
```

does what you ask (it just replaces `where {T, V}` in your code with `where T <: Integer where V <: Int`. See the documentation for `where` for more.

There are some questions I considered about your question. A SVector{S, T} can have the type of T vary in type, but S is a count of elements and must be an Int as far as I know. So the SVector package should enforce the type of S for you. So the `where` would usually be used to vary the second type in the SVector, which you always set to Int here.

Comment: After your MT definition, executing "MT(SVector{3,Int}(1,2,3),SVector{3,Int}(1,2,3))" is giving me an error( still, code i wrote is working).  My foucs was on T and V. I thought that T and V are just works like the concept called  const generic in rust so it will have type annotation. (ex: restrict type of T as Integer). Does S in SVector{S,T} is just number not type thus it is in generic parameter?

Comment: This answer will not work, since `3` is not a subtype of `Integer`. The relationship between `3` and `Integer` is a `isa`-relationship, not a `<:`-relationship.

Comment: I think that since where() requires types as arguments, and your problem is one where you want to act on the value of the integer, not whether it is an integer, I would not use my answer, but instead use something like `if Val(V) - T != 1` in function body and not specify T with `where` at all.